# iTextSharp Parse HTML Memory leak? HTMLWorker.ParseToList or Parse

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, itext

When I try to parse a large html file with iTextSharp, my memory is increasing with 200mb +=

I tried following methods:

```
public byte[] CreatePdfToBytArray(string foundText, StyleSheet styles = null, bool landscape = false)
    {
        using (var d = new Document())
        {
            if (landscape)
            {
                d.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            }
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                foundText = foundText.Replace("<br>", "/n");

                PdfWriter.GetInstance(d, stream);
                var stringReader = new StringReader(foundText);
                d.Open();
                var parser = new HTMLWorker(d);

                List<IElement> parsedList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, styles);

                foreach (object item in parsedList)
                {
                    d.Add((IElement) item);
                }

                d.Close();
                stringReader.Close();
                stringReader.Dispose();


                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

And

```
protected byte[] ConvertHTMLToPDF(string HTMLCode)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Render PlaceHolder to temporary stream 
            var stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            var htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            var reader = new StringReader(HTMLCode);

            //Create PDF document 
            var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            var parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("I hope this works for you."));

            try
            {
                parser.Parse(reader);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Display parser errors in PDF. 
                var paragraph = new Paragraph("Error!" + ex.Message);
                Chunk text = paragraph.Chunks[0];
                if (text != null)
                {
                    text.Font.Color = BaseColor.RED;
                }
                doc.Add(paragraph);
            }
            finally
            {
                doc.Close();
                parser.Close();
                parser.FlushContent();
                parser.Dispose();
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();
            }

            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Both make my memory spike, I know the issue is in the HTMLWorker.ParseToList method or the parse method, is there any way i can clear the memory?

Thanks

Comment: Just so you know, `HTMLWorker` has been deprecated for many years in favor of `XMLWorker` so even if there was a memory leak it probably won't be fixed. How are you measuring memory usage? How "large" is a large HTML file? Is your HTML deeply nested and/or with a bunch of tables? You say "spike" which generally means "up then down", is that what you mean? Or do you mean if you called your code in a loop you would see a steady increase and it never releases? Both examples use a `MemoryStream`, if you get rid of that and just `ParseToList()` and just throw away does it still happen?

Comment: The HTML page is just a big table, the file is 200 kb and about 80 pages, my app pool memory is going up and stays that way --> 200 mb to 400, with the next pdf 600, ... And it stays that way. I also read that XMLWorker is in favor, but I cannot find this class, can you tell me in what NameSpace I can find it

Comment: `XMLWorker` lives in a separate library, http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/files/xmlworker/

Comment: Yea already downloaded after previous comment, testing it now, ty for putting me on the right track, lets see what this does to the memory :)

Comment: You code _is_ creating an array of bytes, are you destroying that byte array when done?